# How to get rid of brackets when displaying a dynamic title in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Currently, my title for the same table reads Avg [Transaction Count] and changes to Avg [Sales] whenever the aggregation method is changed by the user. How can I can rid of the [] ? Thank you

Comment: how are you setting this title?

Comment: I am typing the string "Avg" after which I insert the property control, in this case it's a drop down expression linking the two names displayed on the text area to the two column names (Transaction Count and Sales). When I click insert, Avg is succeeded by ${aggregationSelection} which returns brackets in the titles that I would like to remove

Comment: I apologize I realized that I included brackets in the expression to be returned, which is why the title was displaying them. Thank you

Comment: No problem @KarimKardous